# replace native samsung galaxy s3 email app for gmail app?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, gmail, stock-email-app

Is it possible to disable the native email application that comes with the samsung galaxy s3? I feel that the UI is inferior to the [gmail app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm&hl=en).

If so would this require rooting into my phone?

Comment: If you don't set any email accounts up in the native app, then it won't be used. Just set your accounts up in the app that you do want to use. No need for rooting or anything like that? You can only use GMail accounts in the GMail app, but there are many other email apps in the Play Store that you could install and use.

Comment: If your device is running Android 4.x, you can simply go to *Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications*, scroll to the app, oben its entry, and hit the "Disable" button -- et voila, it's "gone" (in case you need it lateron: It's at the end of the very same list), it will no longer appear in any other place.

Comment: Could you all make those an answer so i can mark them answered?

Comment: @Izzy, this is normally the case, and very well may be on the Galaxy S3, but on my Note 2 it seems that Samsung (or T-Mobile) prevented the disabling of some system apps. For example, I could not disable email, "touchwiz launcher", "t-mobile my account", browser, just to name a few that I tried to disable.

Comment: @chrisjlee Done, and added some more useful hints as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>Summary of comments, as requested by the OP:</sup>

If your device is running Android 4.x, you can simply go to *Settings → Applications → Manage Applications*, scroll to the app, oben its entry, and hit the "Disable" button -- et voila, it's "gone", and will no longer appear in any other place. If you need it again at a later point, it will still be at the end of the list, so you can enable it again.

Note though, that some manufacturers / ROM builders decided to preventing some apps from being disabled. Nothing you can do in that case without root. If you rooted your device, on the other hand, apps like e.g. [Titanium Backup ★ root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) would let you freeze those apps as well.

Note also GAThrawn's comment: If you don't configure the email app, it won't run. Some homescreen replacements (aka "launchers") allow you to hide unwanted apps from the app drawer (e.g. [GO Launcher EX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex)), so you at least can ban them in some way.

Comment: Always glad to help :)